# Keyword that enables certain part of a dataframe in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

A dataframe has 5 columns one of them is like this:

```
colors
12 red
12 red
34 grey
32 cyan
14 black
```

I would like to return only the data that have the word red in in the column colors. All the columns.

code:

```
df[df$colors %like% "red", ]
```

I am making a Shiny app that will read a csv from a certain location (fixed). The user will not be able to change the file that is read, only through the source code.

I would like to ask for a password- like word before the person begins working with the app. Depending the word that he uses, part of the dataset will be available to them.

For example if they pass the word:

```
pass1
```

only `df[df$colors %like% "red", ]` will be visible to them.

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use key-value pairs. In R, this is done by defining two vectors - one as a vector of keys and the other as a vector of values and using names() to 'name' the values. Here's a solution based on the sample data you provided:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# Dummy data
val <- c(12, 12, 34, 32, 14)
color <- c("red", "red", "grey", "cyan", "black")
foo <- cbind.data.frame(val, color)

ui =  fluidPage(
  textInput("pswd", "Enter password:"),
  tableOutput("table1")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {

  # Keys
  passwords <- c("pass1", "pass2", "pass3", "pass4") #....and so on
  # Values
  colors.filter <- c("red", "grey", "cyan", "black") #....and so on
  # Assign names to make key-value pairs
  names(colors.filter) <- passwords

  # Subset data - select only corresponding value for input key
  bar <- reactive({
    filter(foo, color %like% colors.filter[input$pswd])
  })

  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    bar()
  })

} 

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Looks very cool. If I put pass1 for two colors though it only shows one.Why? For example if I put 'pass1' for red and for grey it only shows results for red.